# Azure selecting VS2019 host for windows-latest vmImage

Tags: azure-devops

I have a yaml pipeline in azure containing this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
```

When it runs, I get the following output under Jobs/Build

> Pool: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019

And then later when it tries to build my .net6 solution I get this error

> Version 6.0.402 of the .NET SDK requires at least version 17.0.0 of
> MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 16.11.2.50704.
> Change the .NET SDK specified in global.json to an older version that
> requires the MSBuild version currently available.

The documentation assures me that windows-latest should have Windows2022 with VS2022 (with MSBuild 17).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A post to the developer community revealed that the demands are actually the problem.

Removing demands and requesting the windows-latest vmImage results in a build on windows 2022 with VS2022 (as per documentation).

As stated above, requesting windows-2022 also works even with demands present.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a bug on the Azure-Pipelines side. Instead of relying on `windows-latest`, try locking the version to `windows-2022`:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-2022
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
```

PS: demands are ignored on the hosted pool.

Comment: Thanks, works with windows-2022.
Who to tag to get attention from MS?

Comment: I'd guess the developer community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps or the virtual-environments repo https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues.